# How to copy values to the other N/A values according to another value when conditions are met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on organizing a data frame. and I have come across to deal with the missing values in the data frame in order to move on to the next step.

I have a data frame looks like below. Some raws have a gender value and some don't. I was wondering what I can do to fill in these empty values according to the ID number and its corresponding gender value in other rows.

| ID | GENDER |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | NaN |
| 01 | **1.0** |
| 01 | NaN |
| 01 | NaN |
| 02 | **0.0** |
| 02 | NaN |
| 02 | NaN |
| 02 | NaN |
| 02 | NaN |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| ... | ... |

and Make it look something like this:

| ID | GENDER |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 1.0 |
| 01 | 1.0 |
| 01 | 1.0 |
| 01 | 1.0 |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| 02 | 0.0 |
| ... | ... |

Thank you so much for helping me in advance!

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['GENDER'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bill())`